# How to combine multiple class-validator constrains in Nestjs request class?

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I have two validator classes NameMinLengthValidator and NameMaxLengthValidator

```
import { ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface, ValidationArguments } from 'class-validator';

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'name', async: false })
export class NameMinLengthValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(text: string, args: ValidationArguments) {
    return !!text && 2 <= text.length;
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    return 'Name must be at least 2 characters.';
  }
}

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'name', async: false })
export class NameMaxLengthValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(text: string, args: ValidationArguments) {
    return !!text && text.length <= 12;
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    return 'Name must be max 12 characters.';
  }
}
```

I have to this in every class where I want to validate these constraints

```
export class MyRequest {
 @Validate(NameMinLengthValidator)
 @Validate(NameMaxLengthValidator)
 name: string;
}
```

I want to achieve something similar to this, how can I combine both validators?

```
export class MyRequestCombined {
 @Validate(NameLengthValidator)
 name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use NestJS built-in function to combine multiple decorators.
Example from documentation

```
import { applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';

export function Auth(...roles: Role[]) {
  return applyDecorators(
    SetMetadata('roles', roles),
    UseGuards(AuthGuard, RolesGuard),
    ApiBearerAuth(),
    ApiUnauthorizedResponse({ description: 'Unauthorized"' }),
  );
}
```

source: https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators